# Informatica creates a zero byte file and then can't write to same file

Tags: linux, redhat, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have an Informatica workflow that is supposed to generate a .dat file.

The issues is that the wroflow creates a 0 byte file, but then can not write to the file it JUST created. It's baffling.

The target directory is a linux server, and there is a developer on our team that is able to run the workflow just fine, without this file-writing issue.

However, I have checked with our linux admins and several of them have confiremd that there is no major difference in access/permissions between her linux ID and my own. She is in two more user groups than I am, but I have been told that they would not have anything to do with this issue.

The ID used by the connection object is also in the same user group as my id on the linux server, `enduser`. Therefore it should be able to write to my home directory.

The workaround we have devised is to remove the files using my id, touch the files and then chmod them. This allows the id used by the Informatica connection object to write to the files, but it is not a permanent (or correct) fix.

My best guess is that this is most likely some sort of (very obscure) Linux environment issue.

I am also not able to make any changes to the Informatica workflow or mapping, since it is built correctly and this issue appears to be completely local to certain linux user ID's.

Comment: SELinux? Check the audit log

Comment: Any useful messages in the session log?

Comment: nope, it just tells me that it couldn't write to that file, even though it just created it.

Comment: Do you have a separate command to create the file or you simply get zero-byte file after trying to write to this target? Is there some quota perhaps? Try contacting sysadmins.

Comment: There is no seperate command to create the file, it is created and then written two by the informatica connection object's ID. I have talked to our best Linux admin and he can see no difference between my linux ID's level of access and permissions that would cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does the etluser have write permissions? have you tried running a post session command script for chmod and giving full permissions and then writing into the file?

Comment: by `etluser` I assume you mean the id that is used in the connection object, and yes, that id has write persmission. I can see the 0 byte files in linux with read/write permissions.

Comment: This issue is more complex than a simple permission issue, becuase other developers on our team are able to run this workflow without any problems, and they are using the same connection object with the same id.